# Adding money to a friend's Battle.net account

Tags: battle.net

My friend who doesn't have a credit card asked me to use mine to add funds to his battle.net account so he can buy items in Diablo 3 (he pays me cash in return). I would associate my card to his account, put some money, and then remove the card.

He gave me his email & pass, but when I tried to enter battle.net, it locked his account because, of course, I was entering his account from a different IP that he regularly uses.

What can I do to accomplish this without having to give to him my credit card number and security number? I can't go to his house either because it's far away.

Comment: spending real life money on D3 -______-

Comment: Does your friend have a paypal account?  AFAIK paypal works with battle net as well and its much easier to transfer money that way.

Comment: @spartacus no, he doesn't. He could get one I think, but only for this?

Comment: @LUciano Doesn't stop him from using his Paypal account for other stuff later on, does it? It all has to start from somewhere.

Comment: I'll talk to him about this posibility.

Comment: Wait... So you're going to use your credit card and he will pay back in cash. But you live too far from each other to travel to each others house?

Comment: Skeptical...

Perhaps you could give the Developer Support a call to see if they can allow another connection to that Account via a different IP?

Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Novarg we work together, he commutes two hours from his home to here. I'm not saying going to his house is not a possibility, but I was looking for alternative options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need him to read off to you his authenticator code at the very moment you log (because there is a new one every 10 secs). If he doesn't have one, tell him to get one.

Comment: Yeah, in case this wasn't clear, just have him give you the code that gets sent to his e-mail so you can log on.

Comment: I _strongly_ doubt it's every 10 secs. They usually last from 30 to 120 secs, I'm not sure about battle.net's one, but I would definitely rule out 10. Way too short for anything.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because this is asking for trouble. You NEVER GIVE YOUR LOGIN DETAILS TO ANYONE. It is also NOT ADVICEABLE to use your credit card on anyone elses account. It will get shot down as fraud pretty quick and your friend will have trouble with Battle.Net support if he gets an own card.

Answer (score 2):

Have your friend make his own paypal account, then paypal transfer money (which is free) to him. Then let him transfer funds to his battle.net account from paypal.

Answer (score 2):

You should NEVER log into other peoples account. And especially not use YOUR credit card on THEIR account. Once he has his own credit card, he will have to do a lot of explaining to Battle.Net support why his name is suddenly different and might even get banned for account sharing or stealing. You are not helping him here, you are setting him up for a ban.

The best way to go here is to buy a Battle.Net Prepaid Card in the value you want to gift him. Those are available via e.g. Amazon and other online shops and you can just send him the code via EMail. He can then redeem it for his account.

You can also gift any item from the Battle.Net store directly to him.