# Gifting Battle.net Money

Tags: battle.net

Is there a way that I can buy Battle.net money for someone else?

I know that I can go out purchase a Battle.net gift card at Best Buy and then mail the card to them, but I was hoping for something I could do from my computer. Where Blizzard would just immediately credit their account, or at least email them a code to get the money.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could just log-in with his account on your computer, make the transaction and log-off again

Comment: @Jubatus Yeah that's the solution described [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114960/adding-money-to-a-friends-battle-net-account). It just seems crazy that in this day and age Blizzard doesn't have a better way to handle this. *Take my money!*

Comment: This is actually pretty normal. Even steam doesn't allow direct money transfer, only buying games as a gift. This obviously is a problem when you want to gift in-game content like cards for hearthstone, or a weapon skin for counter strike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't transfer or add to another person's Battle.net balance, unfortunately. Currently you can only purchase it for yourself and gift items to the person you're looking to gift with the balance.

[US Battle.net Support Article](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-balance)

[EU Battle.net Support Article](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-balance)

Comment: Great Link, I assume this is also valid for the US? Pertinent quote: "Battle.net Balance is non-transferrable. However, the Battle.net Shop allows you to purchase some items (such as digital games and World of Warcraft game time) as gifts you can share with others." I guess I'm back to going out and buying a gift card :(

Comment: I didn't even notice it was an EU link to be honest, updated answer with both US and EU articles. There is a slight variation between the two but unfortunately the answer remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a Battle.net Gift Card:

[image]

And send the recipient the code off the back.

**Always use ALL CAPS when typing the codes.** For example:

> EYEH8BNALOANINGAME2

Is the correct way of typing the code at the following link:

https://www.battle.net/account/management/redemption/redeem.html